# Solve $y'= \sin(x+y) ,\ \ y(0) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation $$y'= \sin(x+y) ,\ \  y(0) = -\frac{\pi}{2}, -\infty < x < \infty$$

I tried to denote $z=x+y$ but I got an unfamiliar integral.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: The fact that an integral is "unfamiliar" does not mean that it is wrong... Just become "familiar" with it!

Comment: I tried [this](http://i.imgur.com/NWEPSwj.png), but it looks worng for me..

Comment: If $x+y(x)=z(x)$, then $y'=z'-1$, so that $z'-1=\sin z$. Now you should compute $$\int \frac{dr}{1+\sin r}.$$

Comment: I think you got an extra +1 in there, but you are on the right track.  The solution is an arctangent, as you found.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it [here](http://i.imgur.com/sRJRtfQ.png)
But know I can't use y(0)=-pi/2
I getting zero denominator

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint to solve the "unfamiliar" integral

$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{1+\sin x}\, \mathrm{d}x &= \int \frac{1-\sin x}{1-\sin^2 x}\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int \sec^2 x\, \mathrm{d}x + \int \frac{(-\sin x)}{\cos^2x} \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: But now I can't use y(0)=-pi/2
here is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/H8x3kbG.png
tan(-pi/2)!